# The Operator '$d$' Apparently Having two Different Meanings in Differential Geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, differential-forms

Given a smooth map $f:M\to N$ between smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$, we denote the global differential of $f$ by $df$.

Also, the letter '$d$' is used for denoting exterior derivative of a differential form.
Given a differential form $\omega\in \Omega^k(M)$ on a smooth manifold $M$, $d\omega$ is a $k+1$-form on $M$.

The global differential, on the other hand, is not a form.

Can somebody explain why we use the same symbol for these two separate concepts?

Is there some connection between them?

Comment: Given a choice I usually denote the global differential either $\nabla f$ or $\mathsf{T} f$, the latter is used by also, e.g. [Kolar-Slovak-Michor](http://www.emis.de/monographs/KSM/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case that $N=\Bbb R^n$, $df$ is a ($\Bbb R^n$-valued) $1$-form on $M$. As Willie suggests, some people eschew the $df$ notation for the map on tangent spaces; for example, Spivak writes $f_{*p}\colon T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$.

Comment: The definition of a form which I have been using is the following: A $k$-form on $M$ is a smooth section of $\bigwedge^k(T^*M)$. Under this definition we cannot say that $df$ is a form if $N=\mathbf R^n$, n>1. So there must be a more general definition of a form then?

Comment: Well, yes, I said it was an $\Bbb R^n$-valued form (so it's a section of $\bigwedge^k(T^*M\otimes\Bbb R^n)$. More generally, if $E$ is a vector bundle on $M$, you can define $k$-forms with values in $E$. But now it takes a connection on $E$ to decide how to differentiate such animals.

Comment: Thanks. Guess then it is not a very bad idea to use 'd' for both the differential and the exterior derivative.

Answer (score 3):

This notation is only ambiguous in the case of $0$-forms on $M$, i.e. smooth real-valued functions. If $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, then $df$ could either stand for the exterior derivative of $f$, thus being a $1$-form, or the differential of $f$. However, if we identify $T_x \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}$, then these objects could be considered the same; for as a $1$-form, $df$ would take a vector $X$ tangent to the point $p \in M$ and send it to $d_p f(X)$, just as the differential would.