Two definitions of derivative of one form
Let $\alpha$ be a one form on a manifold $M$. There are two ways to  assign meaning to the expression $d\alpha$:

If we think of $\alpha$ as an element of $\bigwedge ^{1} (M)$, then we can use the exterior derivative to get a 2-form $d\alpha \in \bigwedge ^{2} (M)$.


If we think of $\alpha$ as a section $M \rightarrow T^*M$, we can differentiate it like any smooth map between manifolds and obtain a map $d\alpha : TM \rightarrow T(T^*M)$.

I'm wondering if there is any way to relate between the two definitions.
Edit: Let $x_1,x_2...,x_n$ be local coordinates on $M$, let $x_1, x_2,...,x_n,\xi_i,...,\xi_n$ be corresponding local coordinates on $T^*M$,and suppose $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i dx_i$. Then at a point $p\in M$ the map $d\alpha|_p : T_pM \rightarrow T_{\alpha(p)}(T^*M)$ is given by sending $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}+ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_j}$.
On the other hand, the exterior derivative of $\alpha$ is $d\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n f_idx_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}dx_j \wedge dx_i$.
From the computation, it seems that in the local case we can compose $d\alpha$ with the projection $T(T^*M)\rightarrow T^*M$ to get a bilinear form $TM \rightarrow T^*M$, whose anti-symmetrization will equal (up to sign) the exterior derivative of $\alpha$.
Second edit: It seems as though the bilinear form $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}) = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ is not coordinate independent - and only becomes so after anti-symmetrising, thus I'm unsure whether this local approach can even work.

This seems to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1195440/168433.

Have you written this out in coordinates when $M=\Bbb R^n$?

@md2perpe I am aware of that question (and a few others), but they focus on 0 forms, which I do understand.

@TedShifrin I wrote it out yes, and I found that the map $d\alpha : M \rightarrow TM$ is given by an 2n x n matrix whose upper block is the identity and the lower one gives the coeffcicents of $dx_i \wedge dx_j$ in the exterior derivative. So there definetely seems to be a relation, I am just not sure how to understand it "cannonically".

You mean a $4n\times 2n$ matrix? And how are you getting the difference of partial derivatives? Something is very wrong.

@TedShifrin I was looking at the differential of the map at a single point $p\in M$. Using the coordinates $x_1,...,x_n,\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ on $T^*M$, what I got was that if $\alpha = \sum f_i dx_i$, then $d\alpha$ sends the coordinate vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + \sum_j \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_j}$

You should edit your original post with these details, rather than continuing in comments. At any rate, how are you seeing the coefficient of $dx_i\wedge dx_j$ from this? Do you in any sense obtain a bilinear form on the tangent space — i.e., a map that requires two tangent vectors to be input?

@TedShifrin I edited the post to add details, from the local picture, it seems I could get what I want if I had a cannonical map $T(T^*M) \rightarrow T^*M$, or even just such a projection when we restrict to the submanifold $\alpha(M)\subset T^*M$. For then we could compose $d\alpha$ with that map and get a bilinear form $T^*M \rightarrow T^*M$.
I did think of using the section $\alpha$ itself to split $T_{(p,\alpha(p))}T^*M=T_pM \bigoplus T_p^*M$. But I believe the corresponding composition we would get $T^*M \rightarrow T(T^*M) \rightarrow T^*M$ is just the 0 map.

See this answr for the manifold case of 1-forms. In the local case for any $k$-form $\omega$, the exterior derivative $d\omega$ is essentially the alternation of the Frechet derivative $D\omega$ (probably up to sign and combinatorial conventions for the alternation); see Henri Cartan’s book Differential Forms for more details.

How did you get $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}+ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_j}$?

@md2perpe The map $\alpha$ can be identified locally as the map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ sending $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ to $(x_1,...,x_n,f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$

@Et-. I agree on that, but how did you get the formula?

@md2perpe I took the partial derivative w.r.t $x_i$.

Given $X\in TM$ and $\phi\in C^\infty(T^*M)$ we can define $\hat X\in T(T^*M)$ by $$\hat X\phi := X(\phi\circ\alpha).$$ Is this the definition you use?
